# Cannot connect to ODBC from Python Error: file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")

Tags: python, odbc, pyodbc

I am trying to connect to oracle database using Python on the Linux server by `pyodbc` driver. but I am getting below error:

```
 File "Query.py", line 20, in <module>
    connection = pyodbc.connect('Driver=/usr/lib/oracle/18.3/client64/lib/libsqo                                                                                                                     ra.so.18.1};DBQ=bnpporacleb.chwk19l2i1ki.ap-southeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com/ORCL;U                                                                                                                     id=admin;Pwd=12341234')
pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/usr/                                                                                                                     lib/oracle/18.3/client64/lib/libsqora.so.18.1}' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverC                                                                                                                     onnect)")
```

I also tried making entry in the `odbcinst.ini`:

```
[MyOracle]
Description=Oracle Unicode driver
Driver=/usr/lib/oracle/18.3/client64/lib/libsqora.so.18.1
UsageCount=1
```

But got error:

```
File "Query.py", line 19, in <module>
    connection = pyodbc.connect('Driver=MyOracle};DBQ=xxxxx/ORCL;Uid=admin;Pwd=12341234')
pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'MyOracle}' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
FileUsage=1
```

Below dltest comand is working fine.

```
[root@ip-172-31-33-62 lib]# dltest /usr/lib/oracle/18.3/client64/lib/libsqora.so.18.1
SUCCESS: Loaded /usr/lib/oracle/18.3/client64/lib/libsqora.so.18.1
```

Also, below commands gives mentioned output:

```
[root@ip-172-31-33-62 etc]# python -c "import pyodbc; print(pyodbc.connect('DRIVER=MyOracle;DBQ=XXXXX/ORCL;UID=admin;PWD=12341234'))"
<pyodbc.Connection object at 0x7fba233664e0>
```

Comment: It looks like your successful tests are being run as root. Is your failing Python app being run as root too?

Answer (score 0):

```
ls -l /usr/lib/oracle/18.3/client64/lib/libsqora.so.18.1
```

What permissions are on that file?

Does your Python process run as a user who can read and/or execute it?